# Why do vector-based image files contain damaged characters?

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector-graphics

I'm on OSX 10.8.2 and using Python 2.7.3 and matplotlib 1.1.1. When I export my plots to bitmap-based formats such as JPEG or PNG, the percent signs are correctly rendered as shown below:

[image: correctly rendered percent sign]

However, when I export them to vector-based formats such as PDF or PS, I get this:

[image: incorrectly rendered percent sign]

I have not tested all characters, but other rendering errors are likely. It does not matter which backend I choose, e.g. `PDF`, I always get this ill-formed character using vector-based file formats. I use matplotlib's standard font settings, that is, no customization here.

Do you have an idea why this happens?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a bug in the renderer?

Comment: Have you tried other fonts? Other characters?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No, it looks like that in all my applications that can open PDF files.

Comment: Have you tried SVG as an output format?

Comment: @AlexReynolds Just answered my question myself.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this time I can answer my question myself. In the settings file `matplotlibrc` I had to change the settings `pdf.fonttype` and `ps.fonttype` from the standard setting `3` which stands for *Output Type 3* to `42` which stands for *TrueType*. I'm not an expert in fonts, but it seems that the standard font used by matplotlib is a TrueType font. Therefore, the correct font type has to be set.

In Python:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['pdf.fonttype']=42
```

Comment: You're a rockstar. thanks.  `mpl.rcParams['pdf.fonttype']=42` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

When using font type 3 (meaning the native font format of PDF or PS) the font is subsetted.  There was a bug in the font subsetting code for *some* fonts prior to matplotlib 1.2 or so.

So, while this is a valid workaround, it will make the file much larger.  Better off upgrading matplotlib if you can.